# node.js socket has no response when using domain

Tags: javascript, node.js

i typed according to a textbook example, but no response from Client. it suppose to pop out some error message through domain method.but nothing happen.

server.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var domain = require('domain');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var reqd = domain.create();
    reqd.add(req);
    reqd.add(res);
    reqd.on('error', function (err) {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.write('server got error when responsing to client request ');
        res.end(err.message);
    });
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.on('data', function () {
        nonexist();
        res.write('hello');
        res.end();
    });

}).listen(1337);
```

client.js

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 1337,
    path: '/',
    method: 'POST',
};
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf-8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('response content: ' + chunk);
    });
});
req.write('hello');
req.end('byebye');
```

Comment: @robertklep could you help take a look?

Comment: Could you provide the console on the cleint side, what is shown?

Comment: events.js:16
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:253:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:345:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)```